# Stream to twitch or mixer using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to figure out some way to stream to twitch or mixer.
The best way so far was OBS, but it uses really a lot of CPU.

Will ffmpeg use less CPU toen OBS?
I need to stream web-browser content (video) with soudns from this web-browse.
Twitch and mixer both uses RTMP protocol with h.264 encoding. (I dont know what I just wrote, its just info I found on internet :D)

Comment: Any video encoder is going to use a lot of CPU, unless you can get it hardware accelerated—and even then it still takes some. The majority of them offer hardware acceleration, though you may need to enable it. Or you can offload it to an external hardware encoder.

Comment: @Mufasa [OBS offers Intel Quick Sync and Nvidia NVENC](https://jp9000.github.io/OBS/settings/encodingsettings.html)